# Convert String to Array in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I have a PHP String like this:

```
$string = 'a => 1 , b => 2 , c => 3 , d => 4';
```

which I have built from data from a database, where each `"x => y"` represents an associative relationship between x and y.

I am then transferring this string to the html document (JQuery) and attempting to make an array out of it in JavaScript, so that I may process on the client side.

QUESTION:

Is it possible to create a JavaScript Array out of a string?
For example I need to be able to retrieve the values in the array by calling `'alert(array["c"]);'` or something similar.

NOTE - feel free to alter the semantics of the above string ($string) as necessary.

Any help appreciated guys....

Comment: I think that instead of encoding the array contents in your own format like that, you should use JSON.

Comment: Are you starting with a PHP string like that, or do you have an array in your PHP code that you are then converting to that string?

Comment: I agree, use JSON. Create a map in PHP of the key/value pairs and use json_encode() to transform it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PHP Code

(for instance, a file, like array.php):

```
$array=array(
    'a'=>'I am an A',
    'param2_customname'=>$_POST['param2'],
    'param1'=>$_POST['param1']
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

---

### jQuery code:

```
$.post('array.php', {'param1': 'lol', 'param2': 'helloworld'}, function(d){
   alert(d.a);
   alert(d.param2_customname);
   alert(d.param1);
},'json');
```

You can use this for arrays, remember the `'json'` tag at the end of the request everytime.

Comment: How do I  then alert the entire contents of d?

Comment: Concatenating, I guess: alert(d.a+d.param2_customname+d.param1);

Answer (score 6):

You should look into JSON. PHP has functions to write [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and javascript can decode such [JSON objects and create native objects](http://json.org/js.html)

Comment: +1, don't try and resolve the effect, resolve the cause instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the split() Method in javascript :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 2):

I would do this

```
<?php
$string = "a => 1, b => 2";
$arr1 = explode(",",$string);
$arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $str) {
    $arr3 = explode("=>", $str);
    $arr2[trim($arr3[0])] = trim($arr3[1]);
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myLetters = new Array();
    <?php foreach($arr2 as $letter => $number): ?>
    myLetters['<?php echo $letter; ?>'] = "<?php echo $number; ?>";
    <?php endforeach; ?>
});
</script>
```

which will output this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myLetters = new Array();
        myLetters['a'] = "1";
        myLetters['b'] = "2";
    });
</script>
```